# Verb form of the adjective mild?

Tags: prefix

A coworker (whose native language is not English) asked me to "mild" a letter. He meant to "soften" or "tone down" the message.

There really isn't such a construct in English. But is it true that in German, "mildern" means to make "mild," in the sense that the co-worker meant? That means is there a verb form of the adjective mild?

Comment: Ich würde eher `abmildern` verwenden.

Comment: But just to mention another alternative: abschwächen

Comment: The English word MILDEN means to make mild or milder. But as another respondent already replied, one would probably say "soften the tone of" in this case.

Comment: A suitable English synonym could be 'to mollify', depending on context.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In case of a letter that may be a little too harsh or strongly worded there is a German equivalent:

> In seinem Schreiben übte er scharfe Kritik an den gestrigen Beschlüssen.

Therefore a quite common verb for *"tone down"* or *"softening"* of a message would be:

> "Können Sie Ihr Schreiben bitte ein wenig **[entschärfen](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=entsch%C3%A4rfen&view=1)**?"

In case of a single argument we may also use *"[abschwächen](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/abschwaechen)"*, or *"[mildern](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/mildern)"*.

Comment: How peculiar. Not knowing very much of the language, I would have read your suggestion as `sharpen` in English. This makes the word sound like the precise opposite of the actual meaning.

Comment: @TomW: "ENT"scharfen means roughly to UNsharpen, or "take away" the sharpness.

Comment: @Tom Au: I suppose that's probably fairly obvious to a competent speaker. Its similarity to the English 'en-', typically meaning 'do something to' (eg 'enliven') threw me.

Answer (score 8):

I would use `abmildern`: You could say `Bitte mildere den Brief etwas ab` or `Du könntest den Brief abmildern`.

You may also use  `abschwächen`.

If the letter was very rude, you may also say `Bitte mäßige dich im Ton`. This would be a not so friendly and crude remark.

Comment: *mäßigen* is auch gut :9

Answer (score 2):

In this case `abschwächen` or `entschärfen` would be a better choice, but you are right: To make something more mild is `mildern` or `abmildern` in German. But it is rarely used.

** abmildern**

> Ich mildere etwas ab.
> Du milderst etwas ab.
> Er/sie/es mildert etwas ab.
> Wir mildern etwas ab.
> Ihr mildert etwas ab.
> Sie mildern etwas ab.
>
> Ich habe etwas abgemildert.
> Ich milderte etwas ab.
> Ich werde etwas abmildern.